# Bar plot does not use defined color cycle list

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to define some color cycle lists based on a corporate design. Therefore they should be selectable by the user at a later point. Definitions should be available for bar, pie and regular line plots. Everything works fine for line plots, but I am struggling with the definitions for bar plots. This is where I am currently in my MWE and I don't know why I get black bordered bars only:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
            {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},
            {red,fill=red!30!white,mark=none},
            {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},
            {black,fill=gray,mark=none},},},}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,enlargelimits=0.15]
    \addplot[] coordinates{(5,10) (10,15) (15,5) (20,24) (25,30)};
    \addplot[] coordinates{(5,3) (10,5) (15,15) (20,20) (25,35)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve the coloring of the bars according to defined cycle list?

Also is there a similar option like `\pgfplotscreate<bar>plotcyclelist` that can be used to store a named list and load it later through `\pgfplotsset{<bar> cycle list name=}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pgfplots [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) (v1.17 (2020/02/29), page 214) notes the following:

> Thus, the currently active cycle list will be used if you write either
> `\addplot+[〈keys〉] ...;` or if you don't use square brackets as in
> `\addplot[〈explicit plot specification〉]...;`

Although the explanation is not very clear, this implies that you should remove the square brackets, as they overwrite the currently active cycle list:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
            {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},
            {red,fill=red!30!white,mark=none},
            {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},
            {black,fill=gray,mark=none},},},}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,enlargelimits=0.15]
    \addplot coordinates{(5,10) (10,15) (15,5) (20,24) (25,30)};
    \addplot coordinates{(5,3) (10,5) (15,15) (20,20) (25,35)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The list can also be stored first and then used by a bar plot later. Storing a list is done using the command `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{listname}{list specification}`, which can be used with the axis option `cycle list name`.

MWE (result is the same as above):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{customlist}{
             {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},
             {red,fill=green!30!white,mark=none},
             {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},
             {black,fill=gray,mark=none}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,enlargelimits=0.15,cycle list name=customlist]
    \addplot coordinates{(5,10) (10,15) (15,5) (20,24) (25,30)};
    \addplot coordinates{(5,3) (10,5) (15,15) (20,20) (25,35)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use a custom list by name in `pgfplotsset` then you need the syntax `/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list name={listname}}`. This setting will remain in effect until a new list is loaded, without needing to specify it as an option for individual plots.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{customlist}{
             {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},
             {orange,fill=orange!30!white,mark=none},
             {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},
             {black,fill=gray,mark=none}
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{otherlist}{
             {blue,fill=blue!30!white,mark=none},
             {green,fill=green!30!white,mark=none},
             {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},
             {black,fill=gray,mark=none}
}

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list name={otherlist}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,enlargelimits=0.15]
    \addplot coordinates{(5,10) (10,15) (15,5) (20,24) (25,30)};
    \addplot coordinates{(5,3) (10,5) (15,15) (20,20) (25,35)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,enlargelimits=0.15]
    \addplot coordinates{(5,10) (10,15) (15,5) (20,24) (25,30)};
    \addplot coordinates{(5,3) (10,5) (15,15) (20,20) (25,35)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list name={customlist}}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,enlargelimits=0.15]
    \addplot coordinates{(5,10) (10,15) (15,5) (20,24) (25,30)};
    \addplot coordinates{(5,3) (10,5) (15,15) (20,20) (25,35)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marijn, I think I didn't use PGFplots often enough lately, to overlook this. ;-) Is there also an option to store a cycle list and load it later?

Comment: @TobiBS for that you can use `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{somelist}` with `\begin{axis}[cycle list name=somelist]`, see page 219 of the manual.

Comment: This is what I referred to in my question already, but how do I make a bar plot take these colors? In the end they are stored in a bar cycle list, hence how do I store a list in this space?

Comment: @TobiBS I've added an example to my answer. Is this what you mean, and if not, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The problem is, that you have to manually load your defined list through the axis options, it won't apply if loaded by `\pgfplotsset{cycle list name=customlist}` and this is what I would like to do to use it for all bar plots until I load a new list.

Comment: @TobiBS I've added another edit for using the name in `pgfplotsset`, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for, awesome!